How do I replace the CMOS battery in a P II Dell Inspiron 7000 A366LT laptop?
I have a 366MHz Dell Inspiron 7000 P II A366LT laptop which is in new old stock condition. I'd like to replace the CMOS battery.

What type of battery is required? (CR2032, sleeved/jumpered, etc?)
How is it inserted, and now much disassembly is required if any?

I've read this Inspiron 7000 Service Manual, which mentions a dud CMOS battery on the main board can give various boot errors, but it has no information whatsoever on what type, size, voltage or package the battery must be. The laptop is very modern in the way the optical and fixed disks are all removable by hatches and latches, so the CMOS battery might be similarly accessible, but that would be simply guessing on my part. I'm not going to even think about touching thirty year old zif ribbons without very very good reason.

By the way I am using a considerably newer PSU than the one it came with. :)

Have you opened any hatches or covers to see if it is simply a battery in a holder or is there a connector and some wiring to a battery?

A laptop this old can be tricky to find specifics for, but in general you should first check all covers/hatches/etc that might be hiding access to the CMOS battery. However, since they tend to last several years it wasn't designed as a user serviceable part and thus you need to open the machine.
So that being said, Dell equipment from that era tends to have CR2032 (or similar size) batteries for CMOS. As well, I believe they tended to be shrink wrapped with a simple 2-wire connector and would be stuck to the board with simple adhesive. Remove the battery, cut the shrink wrap open, and you'll probably find a CR2032 or similar battery in a single or stacked arrangement, possibly welded to the wire. Replace that, preferably shrink wrap again (or provide some kind of insulation to avoid shorting) and you should be good to go.
